# Excel conditional formatting: color based on comparison of values in a row

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

how can one format the color of cells according to their values in that row? In this table, I want to give red for the most expensive carrier, green for the cheapest one and orange fro the middle range one, for each row:

[image: Table before]

After conditional formatting, it should look like this:
[image: Table after]

Thank you!

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use 3 color scale but the cells values are compared along the columns, not for each row. So each column has a gradual green to red from top to bottom. Not really what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 2):

Apply Graded Color Scale conditional formatting, but set the `Applies to` range to `=$B$2,$E$2:$F$2`

Then use format painter to copy this conditional formatting to the rows below. You'll end up with a separate rule for each row:

[image]

Format your colors to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with just two rules is to 'standard' fill with orange as much of ColumnsB, E and F as required, select and clear any CF rules from B:F then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(B1=MAX($B1,$E1,$F1),B1<>"")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red Fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Add another formula rule of:

```
=AND(B1=MIN($B1,$E1,$F1),B1<>"")
```

with green Fill.

Select ColumnD and Clear Rules from Selected Cells.

In case of ties green will have precedence, unless the rule order is reversed.